# Error when trying to run appium test through Bitrise

Tags: android, appium, bitrise

I'm trying to get my emulator to run using Bitrise. I can't get past this error.

```
"org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 install /Users/vagrant/git/appium/../../deploy/app-release.apk' timed out after 90000ms'. Try to increase the 90000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'androidInstallTimeout' capability"
```

Here is my .zprofile.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

Here is where Bitrise says the Android Home is installed.

`AndroidHome: /usr/local/share/android-sdk`

Here are my capabilities.

````
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "PixelXL");
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "emulator-5554");
caps.setCapability("buildToolsVersion", "29.0.3");
caps.setCapability("skipServerInstallation", "true");
caps.setCapability("avd", "emulator");
caps.setCapability("avdLaunchTimeout", 60000);
caps.setCapability("adbExecTimeout", 180000);
caps.setCapability("androidInstallTimeout", 90000);
caps.setCapability("ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError", "true");
String appURL = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + "deploy" + File.separator + "app-release.apk";
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appURL);
driver = new AndroidDriver(url, caps);```



I think the Android Build Tools are not installed in the correct place and therefore it is never able to install/startup the emulator. That is my guess at least. I'm not sure if I need to change the path or really how to fix this error. Any help is appreciated.
````